# Read a .txt file line by line, recognising specific characters

Tags: c#, arrays, coordinates, readfile

Basicaly i want to read a .txt file line by line.
As i read each line i wish to recognise any space characters between the doubles, for example
"12.1 34.478 67.9"  as like something like X Y Z co-ordinates.
Once spaces are recognised, i can treat each double value independently, and can do specific calcuations to each.

currently im using this to read lines

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
MessageBox.Show("Line Read: " + line + "");
```

I tried a array based approach like below, but the output was never successful.

```
char[] block = new char[3];
reader.ReadBlock(block, 0, 3);
Console.WriteLine(block);

MessageBox.Show("" + block + "");
```

---

Basic Finished working Code thanks to #Bartosz looks like

```
string line = reader.ReadLine();
var split = line.Split(' ');
var x = double.Parse(split[0]);
var y = double.Parse(split[1]);
var z = double.Parse(split[2]);

MessageBox.Show("X:" + x + "  Y:" + y + "  Z:" + z + "");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you obtain your line, you could:

```
var split = line.Split(' ');
```

Then you can obtain each double:

```
var x = double.Parse(split[0]);
var y = double.Parse(split[0]);
var z = double.Parse(split[0]);
```

(or `TryParse` depending on your error handling needs, you should also check if your split is indeed of length 3).

Note: bewre of the locale settings on your OS, if your file use `.`as float pointing seperator, it mai fail on machine where `,` is set.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
var filename = "c:\\test.txt";
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
var myList = new List<IEnumerable<double>>();
foreach (var line in allLines)
{
    var currentLine = line.Split(' ').Select(i => double.Parse(i));
    myList.Add(currentLine);
}
```

A little bit refactored :

```
var myList = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\test.txt")
                    .Select(line => line.Split(' ')
                        .Select(double.Parse))
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

then split using `var stringlist = string.Split('')`

and `double.Parse` every string in `stringlist`

Comment: That example from 2003 is not a good example for reading a file in 2012.

Comment: That's much better. But reading a file doesn't seem to be the problem; I think your answer should focus more on the splitting and parsing part.